# breeze query where clause is not executed

Tags: breeze, where-clause, client-side

I'm quite new to using breeze and at the moment stuck with something which seems very simple.

I have a API call which returns 4 locations. Then using breeze, I'm trying to filter it down using a where clause as follows:

```
  function getLocations(clientId) {
        var self = this;
        return EntityQuery.from('GetLocations')
                            .withParameters({ clientId: clientId })
                            .where("activeStatus", "==", "0")
                            .expand('LocationType')
                            .using(self.manager)
                            .execute()
                            .then(querySucceeded, this._queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            if (data.results.length > 1) {
                locations = data.results;
            }
            return locations;
        }
    }
```

Ideally, this should give me 0 rows, because in all 4 rows the 'activeStatus' is 1. However, it still shows me all 4 results. I tried with another filter for locationType, and it's the same result. The breeze side where clause does not get executed.

Update to answer the questions:

Following is how the API call in my controller looks like:

```
public object GetLocations(int clientId) {
}
```

As you see it only accepts the clientId as a parameter hence I use the `with parameter` clause. I was thinking that breeze will take care of the activeStatus where clause and I don't have to do the filter on that in the back-end. Is that wrong?

Can someone help with this?

Comment: What back-end are you using?  Can you show what the request looks like (including the url and query string params?)  I think the issue is that your backend doesn't know how to apply the where clause at all.

Answer (score 0):

The Breeze documentation indicates that the withParameters is usually used with non-.NET backends or servers which do not recognize oData URIs.  Is it possible that the where clause is being ignored because of .withParameters?  Can't you rewrite the where clause using the clientID filter?

```
function getLocations(clientId) {
    var self = this;
    var p1 = new breeze.Predicate("activeStatus","==","0");
    var p2 = new breeze.Predicate("clientId","==",clientId);
    var p = p1.and(p2)
    return EntityQuery.from('GetLocations')
                        .where(p)
                        .expand('LocationType')
                        .using(self.manager)
                        .execute()
                        .then(querySucceeded, this._queryFailed);

    function querySucceeded(data) {
        if (data.results.length > 1) {
            locations = data.results;
        }
        return locations;
    }
}
```

I'd try this first.  Or put the where clause in the withParameters statement, depending on your backend.  If that doesn't work, then there might be other options.

Good Luck.

EDIT: An example that I use:

This is the API endpoint that I query against:

```
// GET: breeze/RST_ClientHistory/SeasonClients
        [HttpGet]
        [BreezeQueryable(MaxExpansionDepth = 10)]
        public IQueryable<SeasonClient> SeasonClients()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Context.SeasonClients;
        }
```

And here is an example of a query I use:

```
        // qFilters is object.  Values are arrays or strings, keys are id fields.  SeasonClients might also be Clients

        // Setup predicates
        var p, p1;
        // link up the predicates for passed data
        for (var f in qFilters) {
            var compareOp = Object.prototype.toString.call(qFilters[f]) === '[object Array]' ? 'in' : '==';
            if (!qFilters[f] || (compareOp == 'in' && qFilters[f].length == 0)) continue;
            fLC = f.toLowerCase();
            if (fLC == "countryid") {
                p1 = breeze.Predicate("District.Region.CountryId", compareOp, qFilters[f]);
            } else if (fLC == "seasonid") {
                p1 = breeze.Predicate("SeasonId", compareOp, qFilters[f]);
            } else if (fLC == "districtid") {
                p1 = breeze.Predicate("DistrictId", compareOp, qFilters[f]);
            } else if (fLC == "siteid") {
                p1 = breeze.Predicate("Group.Site.SiteId", compareOp, qFilters[f]);
            } else if (fLC == "groupid") {
                p1 = breeze.Predicate("GroupId", compareOp, qFilters[f]);
            } else if (fLC == "clientid" || fLC == 'seasonclientid') {
                p1 = breeze.Predicate("ClientId", compareOp, qFilters[f]);
            }
            // Setup predicates
            if (p1) {
                p = p ? p.and(p1) : p1;
            }
        }

        // Requires [BreezeQueryable(MaxExpansionDepth = 10)] in controller
        var qry = breeze.EntityQuery
                    .from("SeasonClients")
                    .expand("Client,Group.Site,Season,VSeasonClientCredit,District.Region.Country,Repayments.RepaymentType")
                    .orderBy("DistrictId,SeasonId,GroupId,ClientId");
        // Add predicates to query, if any exist
        if (p) qry = qry.where(p);

        return qry;
```

That's longer than it needs to be, but I wanted to make sure a full working example is in here.  You will notice that there is no reason to use .withParameters.  As long as the Context is set up properly on the server, chaining predicates (where clauses) should work fine.  In this case, we are creating where clauses with up to 10 ANDs filtering with strict equality or IN a collection, depending on what is passed in the qFilters Object.

I think you should probably get rid of the parameter in your backend controller, make the method parameterless, and include the clientId match as an additional predicate in your query.

This approach also makes your API endpoint much more flexible -- you can use it for a wide variety of queries, even if the ClientId has nothing to do with them.

Does this help?  Let me know if you have any more questions?

Comment: Thanks. I'd certainly try that. Will this be suffix even when my API call expects a parameter clientID?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know much about your backend.  What is powering your backend and what is the api entry point you are querying expecting?  If it is not an odata-capable server, it won't understand the where clause and if it is expecting all the querying to be done by parameters, they would have to be defined within the api.  Do you have access to the api, or does it belong to an external group?

Comment: the API is written by myself, and I've included the code in the question. Perhaps I'm doing it wrong. Please have a look and advice,

Comment: @CHAT_2013, I've updated the code with a further example that might help.  Good Luck

Comment: We have included the clientID in the backend for security reasons. For example, depending on the logged in user's permissions, we either use the provided client Id or the user's actual client ID. So that we don't face the risk of exposing unwanted client data to the client level. Therefore, we need that client Id in the API level.

Comment: I see.  Well, for testing purposes, I'd take it out and do everything using where clauses.  If that works, then you could try a few things: 1) try to parse the query on the backend (I'm not sure how to do that, but it should be possible) and check for the clientId, 2) pass all query parameters by the .withParameters option, or 3) come up with a different security approach (I hope you're currently using an https connection at least, or I those client IDs are interceptable).  I'm still guessing that Where clauses and .withParameters are not compatible, givent he stated purpose of .wP.